# Want to change output depending on values of different variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `form` with four `input`s and one `select` with 7 `option`s, six of them with values from 1-6.

When this form is submitted it creates a `li` with the values of the `input`s and the `select`, and that works fine.

The script for creating the `li`:

```
`$('#list_wrapper').append('<li id="placeholder">'+'<a id="placeholder_url">'+'<img id="placeholder_img"/>'+'</a>'+nameUnformat+', '+price+', '+rate+'/6'+'</li>');`
```

This create something along the lines of `<img> A name, a price, 5/6`

If no `price` is specified then I would like it to, instead of a extra comma, just write "free".

And if no image url is specified then it should not make the `<img/>` tag.

And if no rating is specified then it should not only write "/6".

And so on with the `<a>`.

How would I be able to do this? I thought about a `switch` statement but I'm not quite sure how I could do that properly.

.

I guess this could be done using javascript but I'm not sure how, so could you please help me :) and if you need any more of my code or information then ask and I'll edit it in the post

My code:

```
<div id='list_wrapper'>
</div>

<form id='form1'>
    <input type='text' name='item_name' placeholder='Name of item (required)'>
    <input type='text' name='item_price' placeholder='Price of item'>
    <input type='text' name='item_img' placeholder='Direct url to image'>
    <input type='text' name='item_url' placeholder='Url to item'>
    <select id="rating">
        <option value=''>Rating</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
    <div id='click'></div>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#click').click(function() {

            var nameUnformat = $('input[name=item_name]').val();
            var nameFormat = nameUnformat.replace(/\s/g, '');
            var price = $('input[name=item_price]').val();
            var img = $('input[name=item_img]').val();
            var url = $('input[name=item_url]').val();
            var rate = $('#rating').val();

            $('#list_wrapper').append('<li id="placeholder">'+'<a id="placeholder_url">'+'<img id="placeholder_img"/>'+'</a>'+nameUnformat+', '+price+', '+rate+'/6'+'</li>');
    });


        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a series of `if` statements instead of a `switch`; it's going to be really easy, something along those lines:

```
// If the `img` variable is defined (e.g. someone filled out the appropriate
// field in the form, create an `<img>` tag, using that content as the `src`
// attribute, and finally append it to the `li` element.
if( img ){
    $('<img/>',{src: img}).appendTo($li);
    // If the `url` is defined (see above), wrap the `img` tag in an anchor
    // element with that url.
    if( url )
        $li.find('img').wrap( $('<a/>',{href: url}) );
}
// If the `price` variable is defined, create a `span` element with the class
// of `price` (I thought it was useful for styling and manipulating purposes)
// and write its text content like so: “, {price}”.
if( price )
    $('<span/>',{class: 'price'}).text(', ' + price).appendTo($li);
// Same as `price` above, except the text content will be “, {rate}/6}
if( rate )
    $('<span/>',{class: 'rate'}).text(', ' + rate + '/6').appendTo($li);

// Finally append the `li` to the wrapper.             
$('#list_wrapper').append($li);
```

Comment: I can't quite understand what is going on in that codeblock. Can you explain it a little more detailed as to whats going on?

Comment: Sure! Edited with some comments, let me know if it's clear now.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with inline conditions in javsacript ((condition)?true:false):

```
$('#list_wrapper').append('<li id="placeholder">'+ ((url)?'<a id="placeholder_url">':'')+((img)?'<img id="placeholder_img"/>':nameFormat)+((url)?'</a>':'')+((!url)?nameUnformat:'')+', '+((price)?price:'free')+((rate)?', 'rate+'/6':'')+'</li>');
```

Although all of that makes it hard to read/debug if you have to.